# Calculating Variance (without Variance expression)

Tags: numerics, probability-or-statistics, random

I am learning Mathematica on the fly, one of my tasks is to find the variance of white noise. I followed the tutorial for finding white noise by using the code:

```
WN = WhiteNoiseProcess[NormalDistribution[0, 10]];
data = RandomFunction[WN, {0, 10000}];
```

I know I can use the following code to find the variance:`Variance[data]`

However, I would like to find it by using the formula for variance. I checked the reference built into Mathematica and it says I can simply use:

```
Total[(list-Mean[list])^2]/(Length[list]-1)
```

I input data for the list:

```
Total[(data-Mean[data])^2]/(Length[data]-1)
```

When I do this, I don't get the same output as when I use the `Variance[data]` code, but instead get:
[image]

So, I am curious what I am doing wrong? I'm sure it's something simple I am not doing, but after spending a couple of hours wrestling with this, I am breaking down to ask. Sorry if this is a dumb question. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: You must extract the values (path) - see the doc for details under properties of temporaldata...

Comment: I did some digging in there and used:
Total[(data["Values"] - Mean[data["Values"]])^2]/(Length[
    data["Values"]] - 1)

This resolved the same as the Variance expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific approach is as follows.  Convert data to an ordinary list, eliminate an extra set of `{}`, and insert the list into your formula:

```
dta = First@Normal@data;
Last@Total[(dta - Last@Mean[dta])^2]/(Length[dta] - 1)
```

which gives the same result as

```
Variance[data]
```

namely `102.245` for the particular set of random numbers used.

Comment: Outstanding, I was positive it was something small I was missing. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

It is valuable to look at the properties of these complex objects, e.g. in your example:

```
data["Properties"]
```

To do your own variance:

```
val = First@data["ValueList"];
Variance[val]
Total[(val - Mean[val])^2]/(Length[val] - 1)
```

You can compare results of `Variance` and your mimic.

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1]
WN = WhiteNoiseProcess[NormalDistribution[0, 10]];
data = RandomFunction[WN, {0, 10000}];
```

### CentralMoment

```
variance = # /(# - 1)& @ #["PathLength"] CentralMoment[#["Values"], 2]&;
variance[data]
```

> 97.25341025240807

```
Variance[data]
```

> 97.25341025240806

### MomentConvert + MomentEvaluate

```
variance2 = MomentEvaluate[MomentConvert[CentralMoment[2], "UnbiasedSampleEstimator"], 
 #["Values"]]&;

variance2 @ data
```

> 97.25341025240809